# Sharp vertices in model

Tags: vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm having a problem with my model, the edge highlighted with red goes around smoothly as the vertices are rounded off, but the vertices highlighted inside the green circle and all the vertices along its edge are cuspy and the edge seems to stick to them and not go around smoothly.

I want to make the edges smooth around these vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like you're trying to make an object with some simple planes, I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, but maybe share your file?

Comment: I have uploaded the file please check it out in the post itself.

Comment: I don't see the same thing when I open the file, it looks round and smooth, there are some problems though, like you need to recalculate normals, to put the Mirror modifier above the Subsurf, also when you'll apply the Mirror you'll probably have to rework your mesh a bit

Comment: Can you show me what you see when you open the file?

Comment: Oh!! I recaluculated the normals and the problem I was speaking about disappeared!

Comment: What does recaulculating normals do to the model? In case I wanted to trouble shoot my future models.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem but anyway all the normals of your object need to be flipped in the same direction to avoid any problem, so select all in Edit mode and press ctrl N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select everything in *Edit* mode and recalculate the normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. If a face is flipped the modifier won't be able to apply its effect properly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I played some with your model. It seems during modeling some edges became corrupt. What you need to do is select all the offending edges, that should be smoothed by SDS but are not, one by one, hit <kbd>X</kbd> choose Dissolve Edge, then select the 2 remaining Vertices and hit <kbd>J</kbd>. What you will be doing is in fact replacing all erronous existing edges with new ones. Then they become smooth under SDS. Then you can apply Crease to all the needed edges. It's a laborious task, but it works. You need to rebuild all the corrupt edges one by one.

Here I rebuilt 2 edges, as an example.

[image: Edges fixed]

Comment: Both edges are creased, but the one I highlighted in red smoothes, and the other one with the vertex inside the green circle is broken edges.

Comment: can you upload your .blend file, it would be easier to figure out hands on, you can use this site to upload .blend files; https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the file please check it out in the post itself.

Comment: I found a solution, see my answer above

Comment: Actually, Recalculate Normals fixed this issue without having to do the tedious work! Thanks for the tip @moonboots!

Thank you anyway @Aardo!